# Using Codable when JSON input represents multiple subclasses of a Codable type

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, codable

Let's say I have some JSON, like so:

```
{ 
  "some-random-key": { 
                       "timestamp": 1234123423
                       "type": "text",
                       "content": "Hello!" 
                     },

  "some-other-key": { 
                      "timestamp": 21341412314
                      "type": "image",
                      "path": "/path/to/image.png" 
                    }
}
```

This JSON represents two message objects. Here's how I would like to represent them (Swift 4):

```
class Message: Codable {
    let timestamp: Int
    // ...codable protocol methods...
}

class TextMessage: Message {    // first message should map to this class

    let content: String

    // ...other methods, including overridden codable protocol methods...
}

class ImageMessage: Message {    // second message should map to this class
    let path: String

    // ...other methods, including overridden codable protocol methods...
}
```

How can I use the "type" attribute in the JSON to tell Codable which subclass to initialize? My first instinct was to use an enum as an intermediary which would allow me to go between the string representation and the metatypes

```
enum MessageType: String {
    case image = "image"
    case text = "text"

    func getType() -> Message.Type {
        switch self {
        case .text: return TextMessage.self
        case .image: return ImageMessage.self
        }
    }

    init(type: Message.Type) {
        switch type {
        case TextMessage.self: self = .text
        case ImageMessage.self: self = .image
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

However, the init here causes a compiler error-
`Expression pattern of type 'TextMessage.Type' cannot match values of type 'Message.Type'`
Is there a canonical/accepted way for handling this situation? Why doesn't the init here compile when the function getType does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "is" keyword checks if metatypes represent subclasses of another metatype. This code works:

```
init(type: Message.Type) {
    switch type {
    case is TextMessage.Type: self = .text
    case is ImageMessage.Type: self = .text
    }
}
```

Comment: Please could you provide a full working example of this?

Comment: @Stoff81 `MessageType(rawValue: value).getType()` will give you the type for the value, and `MessageType(type: TextMessage.self).rawValue` will return the encoded value of the type.

Comment: Hey, sorry but im struggling to see the whole thing working as one. Cant get it to compile.

Comment: Please could you show me the lines where you actually do the decoding of the data

Answer (score 0):

I would go for this approach:

```
static func createMessage(with json: [String: Any]) -> Message? {
       guard let typeString = json["type"] as? String,
       let type = MessageType(rawValue: typeString) else { return nil }
       switch type {
       case .image: return ImageMessage(....
```

and so on